# PHPStorm: unable to resolve column '$1' in PostgreSQL prepared queries

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, phpstorm

How to get rid of this warning in statements like this:

```
pg_prepare('select * from table where id=$1', array($id));
```

This is no error, but a little annoying thing.

Comment: Screenshot of `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Database` please.

Comment: http://s9.postimg.org/yjr5ndkxb/settings.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using v9.5 -- you really should state such info in your question -- settings screen is a bit different from current stable v9.0.2.

---

Edit your 2nd Parameters Pattern: make sure it has `\` in front of `?` -- somehow it interferes with other patterns.

It should be `\?\d+` at least.

Comment: Thank you! 
And thank you for your advice to state software version.